# raising a complex number to a high power.

Tags: complex-numbers

we should decide whether the following claims are right or not, and explain our decision.

let $w_1,w_2,w_3$ be three different roots for the equation $z^3=1$

a) $w_1^{1991} + w_2^{1991} + w_3^{1991}=1$

b) $w_1^{1991} + w_2^{1991} + w_3^{1991}=0$

I found that:

$w_1$=$1$,

$w_2$=${-1\over 2}$+i$\sqrt{3}\over 2$

$w_3$=${-1\over 2}$-i$\sqrt{3}\over 2$

Now, how do I continue from here? how dow I know what happens when I raise a complex number to very high power?

Comment: Your two statements contradict each other. Anyhow, use the fact that $w_1^3=w_2^3=w_3^3$ to reduce the power of each to either $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
If $z^3=1$, then e.g. $z^{29}=z^{27+2}=z^{27}\cdot z^2=z^2$.

Comment: this is brilliant, didn't think about it that way, that means, if w1,w2,w3 are roots, it means that not only the multiplication of all of them must give 1, but also $w_1^3$=1 , $w_2^3$=1 , $w_3^3$=1, right?

Comment: It means exactly that $w_i^3=1$ for each $i$, yes.